# Is there a way to assign a number to a letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Heyo! I need help assigning a number to a variable and (possibly) help w/ an array.
(For context I'm practicing coding and using ACSL's 2008-2009 junior league Reversi problem)

I just need help assigning a number to a variable and if possible I guess help with the x and o array (o and x are the playing pieces)

My full code at the moment is

```
rev = open('reversi.txt','r')
rev1 = rev.readlines()
o_array = []
x_array = []
locarray = []
"A" = 1                     #This section is the part that doesn't work really
"B" = 2
"C" = 3
"D" = 4
"E" = 5
"F" = 6
"G" = 7
"H" = 8
for i in range(len(rev1)):
    rev1[i] = rev1[i].replace("\n","")
    rev1[i] = rev1[i].replace(" ","")
    rev1[i] = rev1[i].split(",")

#o array
for x in range(1,len(rev1[0])):
    o_array.append(rev1[0][x])
#x array
for no in range(1,len(rev1[1])):
    x_array.append(rev1[1][no])
#location array
for loc in range(2,7):
    locarray.append(rev1[loc][0])
    locarray.append(rev1[loc][1])
```

The stuff in the txt file is

```
2, 5D, 4E, 2, 5E, 4D
4, 6E, 5D, 5E, 4E, 1, 4D
3, 5D, 5E, 6E, 3, 4D, 4E, 4F
3, 3E, 4E, 6E, 5, 4D, 4F, 5D, 5E, 6D
5, 6C, 6D, 6E, 4E, 3E, 5, 4D, 4F, 5C, 5D, 5E
```

(For context I'm practicing coding and using ACSL's 2008-2009 junior league Reversi problem)

I just need help assigning a number to a variable and if possible I guess help with the x and o array (playing pieces)

Thanks and bye!

Comment: What do you want `"A" = 1` to **do**?

Comment: This is where you use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: So the overall goal of what I'm doing is mapping out the board, and numbers aren't letters. If A = 1, then I can get set coordinates like 3,5 or 1,1 to tell the computer exactly where I want my icon to go.

Comment: dictionary `data = { "A": 1 , "B": 2 , ...}` and later you can use `data["A"]` to get or set value.